# Deploying a Teams tab (personal app) using SPFx without full tenant admin privileges

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-permissions

I'm trying to deploy some Teams tab samples (teams-tab-spfx-client) so I could add webparts my team made as a personal app or group tabs. I was able to run this sample on the site's workbench and package it to the sppkg file, but for Teams deployment I don't see that Sync with Teams option the docs show.

[image]

I'm not a tenant admin, but I'm a site collection admin in this particular site (I'm able to run SPFx webparts on it and add new SP apps to the AppCatalog). Couldn't find any settings that would allow me to sync with Teams, so I understand I will probably have to ask someone above to allow me to deploy to Teams, so **question 1**: Is that correct?

Following that I found another Teams personal app sample using the VS Code's Teams Toolkit extension (todo-list-SPFx). I was able to run it on debug mode inside one of my teams tabs, but when I package it (the ZIP package) and try to add to that team I get the following error:

```
"Error initializing application. Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'componentType')"
```

I'm not site collection admin on these sites that MS Teams create when you create a new team. **Question 2:** Do I need to also add it to the App Catalog? If yes, I understand I would have to ask for this permission.

**Broad question:** In general, what I wanted was to deploy SPFx webpart solutions to Teams. I'm not a tenant admin, I do have a few sites where I'm site collection admin. There's also a few MS Teams' teams (no admin). What permissions do I need to deploy those solutions to Teams? I've seen options in the docs where I have to package it to .sppkg others to .zip but couldn't figure out those differences alone. Those could be personal apps or teams tabs. Personal apps would be more interesting because the install would be easier (I understand that I would probably need permission to share this in the tenant store)

Comment: Are you using "Make this solution available to all sites in the organization" (`skipFeatureDeployment` attribute in the `package-solution.json` file) option while deploying the solution?

Comment: Also, check this documentation if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/tools-prerequisites

Comment: Yes Ganesh, the first sample is this one https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-channel-group/spfx I just cloned the repo and tried. I don't see those options to sync with Teams, I also can check the box to make it available to all sites, but I'm not a tenant admin, so I imagine this is useless for me. In the end, I believe it's all due to permission levels.